# Timer update UI when back to timer Fragment

Tags: android, timer, fragment

I have 2 fragments.
On the transaction between them i'm replacing them.
On the second Fragment, i have a Timer witch updating a TextView.
Here is the flow i need.

- 1) Go to second Fragment.
- 2) Start The Timer.
- 3) Go back to first Fragment (While the Timer is running)
- 4) Come back to the second Fragment and keep updating the TextView.

My issue is, when i come back to second Fragment and the Timer is Running the TextView is not updating anymore.

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setFragmentTransaction(null);

}



/**
 * A fragment transaction Method
 *
 * @param fragment the fragment we want to display
 */
public void setFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment) {

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    //replacing fragments new Fragments
    if (fragment != null ) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    } else if(fragment == null && (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)) { // starting with main Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
    }

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();


}
```

}

Main Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private Button button;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.context = context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

      button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mainBTN);

      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ((MainActivity)context).setFragmentTransaction(new TimerFragmnet());
          }
      });


        return view;

    }
}
```

The Timer Fragment:

```
public class TimerFragmnet extends Fragment {


    private Context context;
    private TextView timerTextView;
    private Button startBTN, backBTN;
    private View view;
    private Timer timer;
    private int timerSec;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.context = context;

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
        timerTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        startBTN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startBTN);
        backBTN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.backBTN);


        startBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTimer(180);
            }
        });


        backBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) context).setFragmentTransaction(new MainFragment());
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i("Timer", msg.toString());


            timerTextView.setText(createDateFormat((int) msg.obj));

        }
    };

    private void startTimer(final int seconds) {

        timerSec = seconds;
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.obj = timerSec;
                message.setTarget(mHandler);
                mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                timerSec--;


            }
        }, 100, 1000);


    }


    /**
     * Setting the timer format
     *
     * @param seconds
     * @return
     */
    public String createDateFormat(int seconds) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finnaly did it:
I created a new Class which make all the Timer treatment and in my my Fragment implement his callbacks:
I'll live the code here for any case:

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setFragmentTransaction(null);

    }



    /**
     * A fragment transaction Method
     *
     * @param fragment the fragment we want to display
     */
    public void setFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment) {

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //replacing fragments new Fragments
        if (fragment != null ) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        } else if(fragment == null && (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)) { // starting with main Fragment
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
        }

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();


    }
}
```

**MainFragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private Button button;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.context = context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mainBTN);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)context).setFragmentTransaction(new TimerFragment());
            }
        });


        return view;

    }
}
```

**TimerFragment:**

```
public class TimerFragment extends Fragment implements MyTimer.TimerRuning {


    private Context context;
    private TextView timerUpTextView, timerDownTextView;
    private Button startBTN, backBTN, stopTimerBTN;
    private View view;



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.context = context;

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        MyTimer.getInstance().setTimerRuningListener(this);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
        timerUpTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerUpTextView);
        timerDownTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerDownTextView);
        startBTN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startBTN);
        backBTN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.backBTN);
        stopTimerBTN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stopTimerBTN);


        startBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyTimer.getInstance().startTimer(180);
            }
        });


        stopTimerBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyTimer.getInstance().stopTimer();
            }
        });


        backBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) context).setFragmentTransaction(new MainFragment());
            }
        });



        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimerChange(String remainSec, String startSec) {
        timerUpTextView.setText(startSec);
        timerDownTextView.setText(remainSec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimerStopped(String remainSec, String startSec) {
        timerUpTextView.setText(startSec);
        timerDownTextView.setText(remainSec);
    }
}
```

**MyTimer - Class**

```
public class MyTimer {    

    private Timer timer;
    private MyTimer.TimerRuning timerRuningListener;
    private int remainingSec, startSec;
    public boolean isRunning;


    private static final String TAG = "MyTimer";


    private static final MyTimer ourInstance = new MyTimer();

    public static MyTimer getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            int[] timeArr = (int[]) msg.obj;

            if (timeArr[0] == 0) {
                MyTimer.this.stopTimer();
                if(timerRuningListener != null) {
                    timerRuningListener.onTimerStopped(createDateFormat(0), createDateFormat(0));
                }
            } else {
                if(timerRuningListener != null) {
                    timerRuningListener.onTimerChange(createDateFormat(timeArr[0]), createDateFormat(timeArr[1]));
                }
            }


        }
    };


    public void startTimer(final int seconds) {


        startSec = 0;   

        remainingSec = seconds;
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer running......");
                isRunning = true;
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                int[] counters = new int[2];
                counters[0] = remainingSec;
                counters[1] = startSec;
                message.obj = counters;
                message.setTarget(mHandler);
                mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                remainingSec--;
                startSec++;


            }
        }, 100, 1000);


    }


    /**
     * Setting the timer format
     *
     * @param seconds
     * @return
     */
    public String createDateFormat(int seconds) {

        return String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));

    }

    public void setTimerRuningListener(MyTimer.TimerRuning timerRuningListener) {
        this.timerRuningListener = timerRuningListener;
    }


    public interface TimerRuning {
        void onTimerChange(String remainSec, String startSec);

        void onTimerStopped(String remainSec, String startSec);
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timerRuningListener.onTimerStopped(createDateFormat(0), createDateFormat(0));
            isRunning = false;
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "when i come back to second Fragment and the Timer is Running"? When you go back to your first fragment, the second one gets destroyed and so is the timer. When you "come back" to your second fragment, you are creating a new instance, and it will have a new timer that is not running.

I suggest you to use a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You can start a timer there and send broadcasts every second to update your UI. When your second fragment starts, you register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that will get those updates. When that fragment stops, you can unregister the [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: I'm not killing the timer, when i killing the Second fragment. He is keep running.

Comment: Can you please verify it? From your code, unless you keep a reference to the timer outside your fragment, it is destroyed.